# Procedure that store updated history of table in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables Person with PersonId, Name,Address,Mobile and PersonLog with Id,Name,Address,Mobile,FK_PersonId. I am trying store the old data in PersonLog and Person to be updated.

This is my procedure,  but it is only updating Person and not storing selected(edited) data from Person into PersonLog :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateInsertPerson]
(
@PersonId int,
@PersonName nvarchar(40),
@Address nvarchar(60),
@Mobile nvarchar(15)
)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO
dbo.PersonLog(PersonName, Address, Mobile, FK_PersonId)
SELECT
Person.PersonId, Person.PersonName, Person.Address, Person.Mobile
FROM
dbo.Person JOIN dbo.PersonLog ON PersonLog.FK_PersonId = Person.PersonId;

UPDATE
dbo.Person
SET
PersonName = @PersonName,
Address = @Address,
Mobile = @Mobile
WHERE
PersonId = @PersonID;

END
```

Any help?

Comment: you need to add a `where` on the `insert into ... select ...` that does `where person.personid=@PersonID` probably... what is wrong exactly?  (I would also add a datetime to that table so you know when the change happened, just because)

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? Does the query throw errors, produces wrong results or do nothing ? We don't have access to your tables. So, we cannot find out what happened. I think you should think this before posting such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest these changes... but I don't know what you're after exactly.  Or your data.

I highly suggest adding a modified date to your PersonLog table....

```
alter table PersonLog add Modified_DT datetime default getdate()
```

this code works for me...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateInsertPerson (
    @PersonId int,
    @PersonName nvarchar(40) = null,
    @Address nvarchar(60)    = null,
    @Mobile nvarchar(15)     = null
)
AS
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO PersonLog (FK_PersonId, PersonName, Address, Mobile)
          SELECT Person.PersonID, 
                 Person.PersonName, 
                 Person.Address, 
                 Person.Mobile 
          FROM   Person  
          WHERE  Person.PersonId=@PersonID; 

    UPDATE Person
       SET PersonName = case when @PersonName is not null then @PersonName else PersonName end,
           Address    = case when @Address    is not null then @Address    else Address end,
           Mobile     = case when @Mobile     is not null then @Mobile     else Mobile end 
     WHERE PersonId   = @PersonID;   

END


insert into Person values (1,'kim','123 main st','555-555-5555'); 

exec UpdateInsertPerson 1,'kim';
exec UpdateInsertPerson 1,'ryan';
exec UpdateInsertPerson 1,'taco';


select * from personlog 

select * from Person
```

that way will not insert a brand new person.  this way will...  for this to work, your Person.PersonID must be set like this: `PersonID int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateInsertPerson (
    @PersonId int            = null,
    @PersonName nvarchar(40) = null,
    @Address nvarchar(60)    = null,
    @Mobile nvarchar(15)     = null
)
AS
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO PersonLog (FK_PersonId, PersonName, Address, Mobile)
          SELECT Person.PersonID, 
                 Person.PersonName, 
                 Person.Address, 
                 Person.Mobile 
          FROM   Person  
          WHERE  Person.PersonId=@PersonID; 

    UPDATE Person
       SET PersonName = case when @PersonName is not null then @PersonName else PersonName end,
           Address    = case when @Address    is not null then @Address    else Address end,
           Mobile     = case when @Mobile     is not null then @Mobile     else Mobile end 
     WHERE PersonId   = @PersonID;   

    -- this inserts into Person if they didn't already exist
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
      INSERT Person (PersonName, Address, Mobile) VALUES (@PersonName, @Address, @Mobile); 
    END

END
```

Comment: I am trying on update Person data, and to save the old record in PersonLog, so that i can see what changes were made thry time.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is not working as you are joining PersonLog with Person table in the select statement. As initially this table is empty the condition PersonLog.FK_PersonId = Person.PersonId is false and nothing gets inserted (as FK_PersonId is NULL)
I don't see any purpose of joining the 2 tables to insert the record in Log table. just remove the join condition and include a where clause as Person.PersonId=@PersonID